# Ionic 3- how to open external url in device default browser

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, angular6, inappbrowser

I want to open external url in device default browser. Like for android it should get open in chrome and for ios it should open in safari.

Initially when I tried `window.open(url,"_system")` it was working fine with android. When I tried in ios, it wasn't working.

After some research, I came to know that due to popup block nature of safari, it wasn't opening. Then I disabled the pop-up block setting. Still issue was there. Later I came to know that I need to install InAppBrowser plugin to make it workable.

Hence I followed below steps

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

**Added provider in app.module.ts file**

After installation of plugin, app started crashing on android device. (Not checked on ios).

I don't know the reason. If I remove the plugin, application is working but now I am not able to open url in android also.

Can anyone please tell me how to open external url in android and ios?

Configuration

**1. ionic - v3**

**2. Angular - v6**

**3. cordova - v8**

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution that worked for me in V3 with [App Browser Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)

```
<button ion-button block clear (click)="openWebpage(url)">Open Webpage</button>
```

and the openWebpage method goes like this

```
 openWebpage(url: string) {
        const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
          zoom: 'no'
        }

        // Opening a URL and returning an InAppBrowserObject
        const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_self', options);

       // Inject scripts, css and more with browser.X
      }
```

Comment: I don't have issue with code. Whenever I add the code in app.module.ts as a provider, app is getting crash

Answer (score 1):

change this in **config.xml**

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

and in **app.component.ts**

```
initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();
});
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen$4.run(SplashScreen.java:230)


If I removed the plugin.. everything working fine except url open in browser.

Comment: where are you calling inappbrowser? just at opening the app?

Comment: Whenever I will add it in app.module.ts as a provider, app is getting crash

Comment: but where are you calling this inappbrowser? as soon as the splash screen goes? i think issue seem to be there between the splashscreen and first page